# MySQL INNER JOIN possibly empty transaction table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables
equipment with id and name
transaction log with equipment_id record_type and timestamp

I need to select record from equipment based on filter and the most recent record of type 1 from transaction log if one exists.

(Some Updates)
What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT equipment.id, equipment.name, MAX(transaction_log.timestamp) as last_update
FROM equipment
LEFT JOIN transaction_log
ON equipment.id = transaction_log.machine_id
WHERE equipment.location_id = 2 AND transaction_log.type = 1
GROUP BY machine_id;
```

This executes as I want as long as a transaction log record exists, if none exist I get no results. If I remove the AND transaction_log.type = 1 it works.

Comment: That's what INNER JOIN does.  It must exists.  Use LEFT JOIN instead

Comment: Do you want results if there's an equipment record but not necessarily a transaction record?

Comment: Actually I tried the left join and that works if I leave out the transaction_log.type = 1.

Comment: I want a complete list of the matching equipment records and the last transaction log time if it exists.

Comment: The query shown in this question should fail since the grouping columns do not match what is selected. If you fix that and show the output and the expected output, it might be easier to answer.

Comment: an `outer join` would become an inner join due to the `where` criteria. you should aggregate before joining, or use a correlated subquery.

Comment: And what is `arcade_machine` in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a LEFT JOIN with a change of your WHERE clause.

[image]

```
SELECT equipment.id, equipment.name, MAX(transaction_log.timestamp) as last_update
FROM equipment
LEFT JOIN transaction_log
ON arcade_machine.id = transaction_log.machine_id
WHERE equipment.location_id = 2 AND (transaction_log.machine_id IS NULL OR transaction_log.type = 1)
GROUP BY arcade_machine.id;
```

You also have to change your GROUP BY to make this work. I don't have a good way to test this, so hopefully it gets you close enough to nudge it into working order.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks